# dompdf doesn't show checkboxes

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I am using Dompdf (http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/index.php) as pdf to html converter with php.

But it doesņ't show checkboxes and other input fields.
I am using a code from example and trying to render the following html:

```
    <head><body><fieldset>
  <legend>legend</legend>
  <input type="text" value="input type text"><br>
  <input type="password" value="input type password"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="input type checkbox"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="" value="input type checkbox"><br>
  <input type="radio" value="input type radio"><br>
  <input type="radio" checked="" value="input type radio"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="input type submit"><br>
  <input type="reset" value="input type reset"><br>
  <input type="file" value="input type file"><br>
  <input type="hidden" value="input type hidden">&lt;&lt; input type hidden<br>
  <input type="image" value="input type image">&lt;&lt; input type image<br>
  <input type="button" value="input type button"><br>
  <button>button</button><br>
  <textarea>textarea
    this is a 
    test
    foo
    </textarea><br>
  <select>
    <option>FOO</option>
    <option selected="">BAR</option>
  </select><br>
</fieldset> </body></head>
```

I have taken code from here https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/downloads/list.
And I have copied an example from here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage (just replace html part with above code).

It doesn't show input fields at all.

Examples contains form fields: http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php

EDIT:
I have found discussoin here: https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=79

It says that it is fixed, but not presented in the code, but only in svn trunk. I really cannot find those changes.

Comment: FYI, we have moved the project to [github](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf). The Google Code project is being maintained for historical reasons.

Comment: You should go ahead and download the latest revision of the code. You can clone the repo using git, add it to your project via composer, or download a copy from github or using the nightly downloader at http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf. If none of those options make much sense, use the nightly downloader.

Answer (score 0):

put the css in checkbox
style="height: 15px;width:15px;border:1px solid black;"

Comment: Suggestion : add code fences and the language identifier to highlight the code and make it more readable.